# Print String List with Jgrasp (Java)

Tags: java, string, list

Haven't done this in ages and drawing a complete blank

This is what i have that isn't working

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Three {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int x;
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
    String[] List;
    List = new String [10];

    for(x=0; x < 10; x++) {
      System.out.println("List Ten Words");
      List[x] = scan.next();
    }

    System.out.println("Words are: " + List[x] ); 
  } 
}
```

Need this to take in ten words and print in reverse order.
As is it is taking in the 10 inputs and giving me an error at the end.
Please Help?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need two for loops. One to get the input and the other to print the results.  To better understand the logic, try to think through the steps involved if you had to do this on paper, if someone were to read you 10 words and then you had to type them out in reverse order.

Answer (score 1):

I've just verified that this works:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Three {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

     int x;
     Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in); 
     String[] List;
     List = new String [10];

     System.out.println("List Ten Words");
     for(x=0; x < 10; x++) {
       List[x] = scan.next();
     }

     System.out.println("Words are:");
     for(x=List.length-1; x >=0; x--) {
       System.out.println(List[x]);
     } 
   } 
}
```

BTW: It's a convention in java to name all variables starting with a lowercase letter. The variable named `List` is particularly unpleasant since there is an interface called `List` in the Collections API that programmers reading your code are likely to confuse with your variable.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but isn't it better to suggest the logic to the OP and let him work out the code details himself? Otherwise you cheat him out of the potential benefits from coding it himself.

Comment: Thanks guys. And Hovercraft yes this could be true but at the same time i can now study this code and figure out exactly what i was doing wrong as well as different ways of doing it.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: He's given the question an honest attempt and posted his code. I think it's okay to help the rest of the way from here. If his question had been "How do I write a program in Java that inputs ten words from the user and prints them in reverse order?" with no attempt at coding it, I wouldn't have bothered answering.

Comment: Idk if you guys can help me with my other part of this but i also have to do this in the worst program ever (Visual Logic) And can't figure out how to work with this. Anybody familiar with

Answer (score 0):

```
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in); 
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

        System.out.println("List Ten Words");

        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.print("Name: ");
            list.add(scanner.next());
        }

        Collections.sort(list, Collections.reverseOrder());

        System.out.println(list);
```